# vb6 :create object dynamically

Tags: vb6, object

In vb6, i can do :

```
set object=new class
```

where object is a Object and Class is a class defined in the code.

Now, i want to do the same dynamically, i want to do something like:

```
set object=createobject("class")
```

but it fail because createobject is apparently for activex registered class and not class modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the reason you want to do this is to mimic some sort of interface-like functionality, otherwise it's probably not an ideal solution.

Anyway, you could create a method that gives back a different class depending on the string you provide.

```
function myClassCreatingFunction(className)
    select className

        case: "Class1"
             set myClassCreatingFunction = new Class1
             exit function

        ...

    end select
end function
```

Comment: +1 You've answered the question asked. I'm not sure what `magallanes` is trying to do, but I'd think it has to be better to pass an `Enum` rather than a string?

Comment: i am trying to serialize a complex object then it can send via SOAP protocol but apparently there is not a possible way (not automatically) to convert a usable object back and to a xml.

Answer (score 4):

If you put the class in question in a separate VB6 OCX, you will be able to use createObject to create them on-the-fly.